# Add 'u' prefix to string

Tags: python

this is a dumb question, I know.

I am making a request, the request returns something like this

`"\u003cdiv style=\u0027inline-block\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027fbox\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv\u003e\u003ca"`

Now if I do `print(r.text)` (with `r` being the variable the above string is stored in), it prints it out as it is represented above.

However if I do 
`print("\u003cdiv style=\u0027inline-block\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027fbox\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv\u003e\u003ca")`

It prints out `"<div style='inline-block'><div class='fbox'><div><a`".

So I am wondering, how do I print like the second version.

This might not be clear so to sum it up:

When I print the raw string with `\u003` etc in it, it prints with `\u003` replaced with its unicode character. But if I print it is the response from a request, it prints out without replacing the character.

Comment: Do you use Python 2.x or Python 3.x? r.text looks like you use the requests library. Is this true?

Comment: Python 3.4.3 and yes, requests module

Comment: Have you messed with `str` or `repr` on `r.text`? Also, it seems you have an encoding problem to fix with requests (if that's what you're using). I've never seen unicode values returned from a site

Comment: such a return is because the response is from javascript

Comment: How do you know that the request returns what you show?  Is that how it is displayed by Javascript?   `3c` is a valid ASCII character : `<`.  Once it is stored in a (Python 3) string object then no amount of manipulation will restore it.

Comment: BTW, your test should `print("\u003c")`, not "\u003" !

Comment: that is how it is displayed by javascript

Comment: Are you perhaps looking at **JSON** data? JSON uses `\uhhhh` escapes *too*, and it is common for HTML embedded in JSON to be escaped using such sequences. Use `json.loads()` in that case.

Comment: @Will: Then treat it as JSON. `\uhhhh` hex sequences in JSON and Javascript are like those in Python strings, but when it comes to characters outside the BMP Javascript and JSON use surrogate escapes (e.g. pretend it's UTF-16), while Python would use `\U000hhhhh` sequences instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like r.text is being stored as a raw string. i.e.

```
r.text = r"\u003cdiv style=\u0027inline-block\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv class=\u0027fbox\u0027\u003e\u003cdiv\u003e\u003ca"
```

In order to convert it to unicode, you need the [codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) module:

```
import codecs
print(codecs.decode(r.text, 'unicode_escape'))
```

Comment: This is almost certainly JSON instead, and there are subtle differences between how Python and JSON use `\uhhhh` escapes. Those can matter when decoding.