# How to decode UTF-16 to japanese in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I am just start to learn python, and want to decode the url info into japanese word.

```
>>> s1 = '\u4e2d\u99ac\u8fbc\u30cf\u30a4\u30c4'
>>> print s1 
\u4e2d\u99ac\u8fbc\u30cf\u30a4\u30c4
>>> print u'\u4e2d\u99ac\u8fbc\u30cf\u30a4\u30c4'
中馬込ハイツ
```

I think it is a really basic problem, and I have search for utf-16, but it didn't work out. How can I print s1 and get the japanese words?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** An even better way:

```
import codecs

s1 = '\u4e2d\u99ac\u8fbc\u30cf\u30a4\u30c4'
print (codecs.decode(s1,'unicode-escape'))
```

(from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41616022/add-u-prefix-to-string))

**Original answer:**

What about adding `u` before your string? like this:

```
s1 = u'\u4e2d\u99ac\u8fbc\u30cf\u30a4\u30c4'
print s1
```

if you already have the string, like on your question, I would do this:

```
s1 = '\u4e2d\u99ac\u8fbc\u30cf\u30a4\u30c4'
string = eval ("u'"+s1+"'")
print (string)

# or you can do this:
print (eval ("u'"+s1+"'"))
```

There might be a better way, but this works.

Note that some terminals won't display unicode characters like this. It works for me under Ubuntu, but not under Windows 10.

Comment: It worked on windows 10, eval() is what it needed! 
Thank you so much!

Comment: I edited the answer, there's a better way, without eval. Use `codecs` instead.

Comment: @Shapi, If my answer solved your problem, could you please click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
  print(eval ("u'"+s1+"'"))
except:
  print(eval(s1))
```

Will work for sure, I was stuck in similar issue
Please do vote if it works..